# Is cross-posting the same question on two relevant Stack Exchange sites OK?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on the new literature.SE beta about the quality of literary translation of novels from Japanese to English. I thought it was more a literature question at the time but opinion on lit.SE has been divided whether it belongs here or there:

> [Why is literature translated from Japanese always so clunky?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/418/why-is-literature-translated-from-japanese-always-so-clunky)

On reflection I thought both groups would have complimentary light to shed on the question since their perspectives are likely to be quite different.

But does Stack Exchange have a policy banning or encouraging cross posting questions? Or does it not come up very much?

Answer (score 4):

As a general rule, **[NO.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que)**

There *are* specific instances where a question is on-topic for multiple sites *and* you wish to garner answers from different perspectives. But note that if your question is so broad and nonspecific that it *can* be asked without change on multiple sites, there's a pretty good chance you've abdicated responsibility for asking a good question in the first place: seeing your question closed as "Not constructive" on multiple sites isn't going to make you happy!

So in these (rare!) cases where it seems appropriate, **do not simply copy the question verbatim** from one site to another. Tailor it to the audience you are addressing, and ask for the type of answer you wish to receive.

---

For the example given ("Why is literature translated from Japanese always so 'clunky'?"), it's clear to me that this question was written with the Literature.SE audience in mind: a general observation is made and then solidified by referencing a specific author's work, the specific question is for references to existing discussions of this perceived phenomenon, and only at the end are specific examples of wording / phrasing given.

Assuming *any* of this is on-topic for *this* site, my guess is that they would be the implied cultural aspects and explicit examples of word-choice / phrasing. Reworked to emphasize the areas that are the specialty of the experts here could produce a rather different question... albeit one on the same general topic. And at that point, what you're doing isn't really "cross posting" anymore!

Comment: Good point. I think asking a different version of the question would be good for this site. But I think it would involve specific examples to be of value and I'm asking from memory without any such books around right now.

Answer (score 3):

It's a gray area, but I think it belongs there, and posting it on JLU might get it closed as off-topic.  You're not asking a question about Japanese usage, after all--you're asking about English translation.  Granted, this community might be more likely to have the *knowledge* to answer the question, but that doesn't guarantee that the question is on-topic.

Comment: Well it's "Japanese **Language &** Usage" but I do agree with you. If there were a translation SE it might be on topic there (depending on their scope) but it looks like remaining a proposal for a while yet. But this makes me think SE should have a mechanism for "advertising" questions from one site on other sites where the question has some relevance...

Answer (score 1):

If you ask a question in more than one place, please always add mutual links to the other copies.  It is always frustrating to me when I answer a question and later learn that the question was already answered somewhere else.  This makes me feel that my time was wasted.

Comment: Yes I would certainly add links back and forth and mention that the question was cross-posted.